# Best way to draw a flowchart in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

After going through some flowchart examples in `tikz` and some examples in TexSX, I understand that people generally adopt two techniques to draw flowchart diagrams in `tikz`

- Define all types of blocks you need using `\tikzset`. Place the nodes according to their relative position, starting from the first node, and then draw the lines connecting them.
- Define all types of blocks you need using `\tikzset`. Draw all the nodes in a `matrix`. Leave empty spaces if you don't have a node in a particular entry in the `matrix`. Then connect all the nodes.

I was curious to know, which approach is better in general. Could someone point out to the advantages and disadvantages of this methods.

Comment: I find the first approach is better as often I have to add something that I forgot somewhere in between the diagram. Since everything was placed relative to other nodes, the diagram readjusts itself as desired.  By placing all the nodes in a matrix it is harder to insert nodes, or move a block of nodes later.

Comment: nice!!,I waited for other suggestions, seems like not much is happening. Could you write that as an answer please,,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Converting comment to answer as requested:

I find that the first approach of using relative positioning is better as often I have to add something that I forgot somewhere in between the diagram. Since everything was placed relative to other nodes, the diagram re-adjusts itself as desired.

By placing all the nodes in a matrix it is harder to insert nodes, or move a block of nodes later.

### References:

- [How to typeset flowcharts in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/723/how-to-typeset-flowcharts-in-latex)
- [Flowchart using Tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78693/flowchart-using-tikz)